# xamarin forms stretch button all over the grid column

Tags: android, ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to have to buttons side by side without a space.

I tryed it with a grid, but I couldn't find out how to do it.

This is my code:

```
                <StackLayout  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End" Spacing="0" >

                <Label Text="Hello " FontSize="Medium"/>
                <Label FontSize="Small">This sould be a text?</Label>
                <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="#6fcd11" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                <Grid Padding="0" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" BackgroundColor="Aqua" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Ja"></Button>
                    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Nein"></Button>

                </Grid>

            </StackLayout>
```

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE:

The result is like this but, but I would like to fill it up that the blue background is not visible. I would like remove the space between this two buttons.

[image]

Comment: There is no problem with your code , were you  sure attaching the complete code ?

Comment: This works fine for me on both Android and iOS. No space between or around the buttons. Could be a style, custom renderer or on Android an Android style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding an margin of the grid should be set to 0, then it works great...

Answer (score 1):

By Coding you can do something like this.

```
new StackLayout
    {
        Spacing = 0,
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
        Children = 
        {
            new Button
            {
                Text = "Ja",
            },
            new Button
            {
                Text = "Nein",

            },

        }
    }
```

Comment: set margin=0 of that StackLayout

Comment: nope unfortunateliy it is not working with this margin

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve it by making margin parameter minus,

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VideoApp"
         x:Class="VideoApp.CallHistoryPage">
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="End" Spacing="0" Padding="0">

    <Label Text="Hello " FontSize="Medium"/>
    <Label FontSize="Small">This sould be a text?</Label>
    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="#6fcd11" 
 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    <Grid Padding="0" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" 
BackgroundColor="Aqua">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="-5,-7,-5,-6" Text="Ja">
</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="-5,-7,-5,-6" 
Text="Nein"></Button>

      </Grid>

   </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

[image: Output:]

Landscape Mode:

[image]

Comment: This is too unsafe, different versions and resolutions might show different outcomes.

Comment: I have tested it on 3 different emulator having different resolution, in both portrait as well as in landscape mode. Its working fine with same margin i have written in code.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the actual underlying button that you are rendering.
There are 2 Buttons in Android right now, that you can inherit from, in your [CustomRenderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/):

```
public class YourButton_Droid : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.ButtonRenderer 

public class YourButton_Droid : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ButtonRenderer
```

I guess right now, your app is rendering the AppCompat.ButtonRenderer.
It has a built in shadow, which creates the margin in your case. Using the Android.ButtonRenderer will make you lose your Material Design (touch response, shadow etc.) on your button, but the margin might as well be gone.

If you dig deep into the android button world, you might use the AppCompat one as well, removing the margin through your custom renderer code.

Good Luck!